# Build when using a filename that contains "-element"

Tags: dart

When I create a new dart web application with webui support, the generated project works fine. But when you rename for example the generated file "xclickcounter.html / .dart"  with for example: "counter-element.html" resp "counter-element.dart"  and change the corresponding occurrences accordingly, i get errors like:

```
`Unhandled exception:
FileIOException: Cannot retrieve full path for file 'web\packages' (OS Error: The system cannot find the file specified  
errno = 2)
Stack Trace:
_File.throwIfError (dart:io:1208:7)
_File.fullPathSync (dart:io:1097:17)
symlinkPubPackages (package:web_ui/dwc.dart:157:49)`
```

I dont mind, not being able to use "-element" in the file name, but there maybe many more other restrictions to filenames. 
Does anyone knows what all the restrictions are?

Comment: This works just fine. Are you sure you have changed every occurence?

Comment: What OS version and Dart Editor version are you using? Also, are you sure the above is a full stack trace and error?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work fine. Most likely you either didn't change something, or something is cached in the browser. Try clearing the browser cache, doing Ctrl+Refresh and/or restarting the web server.

Comment: As far as I know this was a bug which was fixed several months ago. In Dart according to the style guide file names should not contain a dash and therefore this wasn't tested at first.

Comment: Ah, that would also explain it! :D